# Streaming m3u8 audio in android without vitamio

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have written above codes from android.developer.com site for streaming m3u8 url. Here is my codes.

```
String url = "http://... .m3u8"; // your URL here
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

But it is not workinng. here is my LogCat.

```
07-18 12:28:32.920: E/MediaPlayer(591): Error (1,-1004)
```

I have tried most ıf the codes on the internet but no one has worked. How to stream m3u8 in Android?